# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Not working on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, outlook, office-interop, iis-express

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook is not working on local IIS but it is working on IIS express while debuging.but when i publish app it is not runing on IIS8.

```
        Application OutlookApplication = new Application();            
        MailItem email = (MailItem)OutlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        email.Display();
        email.Recipients.Add("careers@acb.com; bilal@abc.com;");
```

Giving Exception on IIS not on localhost.

Exception:
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.

Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.