# Microsoft Office Interop Outlook working on local visual studio and not working on iis server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, outlook

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var lst = new List<Msg>();
oNS.Logon("support@**.com", "*****", false, true);
inboxFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
for (int counter = 1; counter <= inboxFolder.Items.Count; counter++)
{
    dynamic item = inboxFolder.Items[counter];
    item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)inboxFolder.Items[counter];
    var msg = new Msg();
    msg.subject = item.Subject;
    msg.senderName = item.SenderName;
    msg.body = item.Body;
    if (item.UnRead == true)
    {
        lst.Add(msg);
    }
}
return View(lst.ToList());
```

Comment: ¿Did you check if your server has installed Microsoft Office? also, please edit your question ading more details about what problems you're facing with the implementation of this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Not working on IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587955/microsoft-office-interop-outlook-not-working-on-iis-8)

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385136/1386991